# Do I need to use @Remote when I want to expose an EJB to a different application on same app server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I have a @Stateless @Local Bean successfully deployed in an ear.  I can see the new EJB 3.1 standard global JNDI name when I browse the JNDI tree.  (java:global/product/product-ejb/ProductManagement)

I want to use this EJB in a *different* application on the *same* app server.  Do I need to add a remote interface for this EJB?

Comment: From the JEE tutorial:
"[Local clients] must run in the same application as the enterprise bean it access."

It appears from this that the answer is YES. But I would still like to get another opinion.

Comment: Hm... I have a little question, how do you call an EJB from another application? Which classes do you have to put into classpath of your calling application? Would remote interface class be enough?

Comment: @Vladimir Short answer - yes. I have had a good experience with Maven generating the ejb-client artifact that I include in the second app.  This is probably a good candidate for a separate question though so someone can give a full answer and the community can benefit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inter-application access to the local client view is not required by the specification but *might* be optionally supported by your container. If you want your application to be portable, you shouldn't rely on it and use a Remote interface (a decent container should optimize calls inside a same JVM anyway). From the EJB 3.1 specification:

> #### 3.2.2 Local Clients
>
> Session beans may have local clients.
>   A local client is a client that is
>   collocated in the same JVM with the
>   session bean that provides the local
>   client view and which may be tightly
>   coupled to the bean. A local client of
>   a session bean may be another
>   enterprise bean or a web component.
>
> Access to an enterprise bean through
>   the local client view requires the
>   collocation in the same JVM of both
>   the local client and the enterprise
>   bean that provides the local client
>   view. The local client view therefore
>   does not provide the location
>   transparency provided by the remote
>   client view.
>
> **Access to an enterprise bean through
>   the local client view is only required
>   to be supported for local clients
>   packaged within the same application
>   as the enterprise bean that provides
>   the local client view. Compliant
>   implementations of this specification
>   may optionally support access to the
>   local client view of an enterprise
>   bean from a local client packaged in a
>   different application**. The
>   configuration requirements for
>   inter-application access to the local
>   client view are vendor-specific and
>   are outside the scope of this
>   specification. Applications relying on
>   inter-application access to the local
>   client view are non-portable.
>
> ...

#### References

- EJB 3.1 Specification

  - Section 3.2.2 "Local Clients"

Comment: +1 Spot on.  Most the vendor's I've compared notes with have automatic optimization of remote calls happening in the same vm.  Do be careful though that non-optimizers often do not pass transaction and security information on remote calls in the same vm.  The sneaky way to check is to see if you have the same thread on the both sides of the intra-vm remote invoke.  If you do not, then bad luck, you hit the full remoting layer and picked up a new thread from the thread pool on the way back into the vm.

Comment: @David Thanks David. I really appreciate reading your comments and answers with all these priceless details. Thank you very much for sharing all this.

Comment: The Doc is not very precise by saying "collocated in the same JVM". They should say that 'Local EJB' works only when calling from the same EAR. It is quite limited.